Non Browser backend workflow issues when using xero-api
I'm building a PHP backend non-browser feature on our app where we can generate invoices which are accessed by our clients in their Xero accounts. Is there a way I can authenticate and access the accounting api without obtaining an access as part of the normal browser based Oauth2 flow? Previously, when using other platforms there has been a way of connecting my app to the platform so that the need for user permission granting is not required.
I was expecting there to be something in the docs referencing how to 'connect' our backend app within Xero and then for us to be able to follow a different Auth flow than the one which uses access tokens. I am currently trying something like this:
$provider = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
                'clientId'                => config('services.xero_invoices.client_id'),
                'clientSecret'            => config('services.xero_invoices.client_secret'),
                'redirectUri'             => config('services.xero_invoices.redirect_uri'),
                'urlAuthorize'            => 'https://login.xero.com/identity/connect/authorize',
                'urlAccessToken'          => 'https://identity.xero.com/connect/token',
                'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => 'https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Organisation'
            ]);

            $options = [
                'scope' => ['openid email profile offline_access accounting.settings accounting.transactions accounting.contacts accounting.journals.read accounting.reports.read accounting.attachments']
            ];

            $authorizationUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl($options);
//
            $state = $provider->getState();

            $accessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
                'code' => $state
            ]);

and I get an 'invalid_grant' error when calling the $provider->getAccessToken method.
Thanks


I get an 'invalid_grant' error when calling the $provider->getAccessToken method.

This is probably because you're trying to use state (defined in RFC 6749§4.1.1) as your authorization code (defined in RFC6749§4.1.2), which are not the same thing.

Is there a way I can authenticate and access the accounting api without obtaining an access as part of the normal browser based Oauth2 flow?

Xero provides this explicitly as part of the authorization flow method they refer to as Custom Connections, which under the hood implements the OAuth2 client credentials authorization flow (see also: RFC 6749§1.3.4).
Based on the docs linked above, it seems Custom Connections is the only method by which you can reliably authenticate to the Accounting API without requiring a user in the loop to delegate their personal access. Whether this will work for you or not will be dependent on a number of factors, but primarily:

Where your Xero organization is based (Custom Connections is only supported for Xero organizations in Australia, New Zealand and the UK)
Whether the Xero organization to which you're trying to integrate has or can purchase the associated Custom Connection subscription for an additional fee

